# Does Kie execution server (Or Drools server)support High Availability?

Tags: drools, high-availability, drools-fusion

I'm newbie to Drools. For powerful drools fusion or timer based rule, most of them are stateful. So, an obvious issue is coming: if the server of the stateful session is down, is that possible to recover the session by Kie execution server?

For example, I start a timer(int:30s) rule, but the server that hosts the ksession is down after 15s. How to recover it?

I've read some of the blogs like:

http://mswiderski.blogspot.com/2016/04/kie-server-clustering-and-scalability.html

http://planet.jboss.org/post/unified_kie_execution_server_part_1

I've also read a little bit about the VFS Clustering in official doc. But I'm still confused about is there an easy way to achieve my case?

Thanks,

Comment: have you ever found an answer? Based on the author's comment in the 1st link you provided, I understand that statefull sessions cannot be shared/HA between JVMs.